# How group by count from multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 different tables, country, city, and customer. Tables are shown below:

country table:

```
id   country_name
1    UK
2    US
3   Brazil
:    
n   Canada
```

city table

```
id  city_name  postal_code  country_id
1    London        30090         1
2    Dallas        20909         2
3    Rio           29090         3
4    Atlanta       30318         2
:
n    Vancouver     32230         n
```

customer table

```
id    customer_name     city_id
1        John             1
2        Pete             3
3        Dave             2
4        May              2
5        Chuck            4
6        Sam              3
7        Henry            3
```

***country.id is references city.country_id, and city.id is references customer.city_id

I want to write a query that can extract the country name, city name and the count of the customer of the associate city. But with one condition, the query will return all cities with more customers than the average number of customers of all cities

It will look something like below, this is the correct output

```
UK London 2
Brazil Rio 3
```

but I kept getting this output, which isn't correct

```
UK London 2
US Dallas 2
US Atlanta 1
Brazil Rio 3
```

I fixed my SQL query but it doesn't give me the result that I want

```
SELECT country.country_name, city.city_name, COUNT(customer.city_id) from country 
JOIN city on country.id = city.country_id 
JOIN customer on city.id = customer.city_id
Group by city_name,country.country_name;
```

I am wondering how can I do this and fix my code?

Answer (score 1):

add country.country_name in group by

```
SELECT country.country_name, city.city_name, COUNT(customer.city_id) from country 
JOIN city on country.id = city.country_id 
JOIN customer on city.id = customer.city_id
Group by city_name,country.country_name
```

Comment: Thanks! but I actually forgot one condition with this query. I just updated my post. Would you mind help me take a look of it?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing country.country_name in the query it will give you error. As a general rule **all columns on which aggregate function is not applied should be part of group by clause**.

So either you write your query without country_name in the select or add country_name in the group by clause.

Comment: Thanks but I actually forgot one condition with this query. I just updated my post. Would you mind help me take a look at it?

Comment: Please complere correct sample data, yuou have to use having clause and compare it with avg customers per city.